# multidimensional array error - unidentified index

Tags: php, mysqli

As far as I know I have defined the variable, however I am getting the following error :

> Notice :  Undefined index: headerid in ..

```
function group_items($db_results) {
  $data = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_results)) {
    $title_id = htmlentities($row['TitleID']);
    $title = htmlentities($row['MainTitle']);

    // group Main Title by title id
    $data[$title_id]['title'] = htmlentities($row['MainTitle']);

    // group data by title id
    $data[$title_id]['data'][] = array( 
      'headerid' => $row['headerid'],
      'title'     => htmlentities($row['title']),
      'content'   => htmlentities($row['content'])
      );
  }

// testing
if (isset($data['headerid'])) {
        echo "Yes";
    } else {
         echo "NO";
     }

      return $data;
    }
```

When I tested using both `isset()` and `array_key_exists` for true / false it resulted in false.

When using print_r I get the following:
Array ( [1] => 
    Array ( [title] => Promising practices regarding general principles of community policing [data] => 
        Array ( [0] => 
           Array ( [a] => 1 [title] => Initiating and developing coordination and collaboration actions between law enforcement agen [content] => Good cooperation and coordination relations between .... more content here

Comment: `headerid` is a key in a sub-array, not in `$data`.

Comment: '*When i tested using both isset() and array_key_exists for true / false it resulted in false*.' - Well, that is the issue, no?

Answer (score 0):

`$data['headerid']` is not defined in you code.

Try `Print_r($data);` to check array elements.

At testing you need to edit your code to

```
isset($data[$title_id]['data'][0]['headerid']))
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit , I answered from phone so I can't style the answer.

Comment: This helped with the testing since now the variable isset is true.   However the error is still there :/

Comment: use Print_r($data); to check array elements and understand whats the array form.
do you still see this Notice : Undefined index: headerid !?

Comment: I used that and everything seems ok but the error still shows

Comment: if you still see this Notice : Undefined index: headerid
the reason is : 
    'headerid' => $row['headerid'],
headerid is not exist in your table or may be you forget to add this column at
    select headerid from table

Comment: I used Select * to get the content from the table.   I am also getting 2 more columns from the same table and don't get an error.

Comment: Can you write the result to print_r($row); here

Comment: I'll put it as a comment above

Comment: Array ( [1] => Array ( [title] => Promising  [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [a] => 1 [title] => Initiating  [content] => Good cooperation . ) [1] => Array ( [a] => 2 [title] => Improve [content] => ) [2] => Array ( [a] => 3 [title] => Increase  [content] => Raising public.. ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [title] => Another title [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [a] => 11 [title] => Title [content] => There's no name2 column in either CUSTOMER table - you need to rearrange the customer name columns, swapping for null to match the desired output.  )  ... ) ) ) )

Comment: print_r($row); not  print_r($data); 
you should write 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_results)) {
print_r($row);